# Sqlalchemy query filter text not working but direct single quote string works

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-functions

I have code like this -

```
import repository as repo

database_session = repo.session

def XXXFun(customerId):
    customerParam = text(customerId)
    subq = database_session.query(Customer).filter(Customer.customer_id == '012db01b-df99-e511-810a-3863bb358f50')
    dataa = subq.all()
    customer = database_session.query(Customer).filter_by(customer_id = customerParam).all()
```

The subq & dataa part works fine, but not the customer object, and I cannot figure it out why.

Repo class -

```
   SQLConnectionString = os.environ.get("AzureSQLConnectionString")
   SQLConnectionString = urllib.parse.quote_plus(SQLConnectionString) 
   SQLConnectionString = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % SQLConnectionString\
   
   engine = create_engine(SQLConnectionString)
   Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
   session = Session()
```

Can anyone help please? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't need to call `.text()` on the value - SQLAlchemy (in fact, PyODBC) will handle the quoting automatically.  Use `.text()`  for raw SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sqlalchemy query filter text not working but direct single quote string works

Reason of occurring the error is converting `customerId` to `text()`. As @snakecharmerb suggests when `pyodbc` is used then it is no need to use of **text()**. Below code is tried without using it and Sqlalchemy query filter works correctly.

```py
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'NewCustomer'

    Id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    
server = '*****'
database_name = 'SampleDb'
username = 'admin6391'
password = '*****'  
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

conn_str = f"mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database_name}?driver={driver}"

engine = create_engine(conn_str)

Base.metadata.bind = engine

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
database_session = Session()

def XXXFun(customerId):   
    customerParam = customerId   
    customer = database_session.query(Customer).filter_by(Id=customerParam).all()
    return customer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    customer_data = XXXFun('012db01b-df99-e511-810a-3863bb358f50')
    for customer in customer_data:
        print("Customer ID:", customer.Id)
    print("*********")    
    print(customer_data)
    database_session.close()
```

**Output:**

```js
Customer ID: 012db01b-df99-e511-810a-3863bb358f50
*********
[<__main__.Customer object at 0x000001AF67C49A10>]
```